# Magento watermark Display only first image

Tags: magento-1.9, watermark

Each product in my web watermark showing first image only :

**Here is the link** - https://www.mustthai.com/index.php/our-products/desserts-processed-fruits/sun-dried-banana-with-honey-lantong-155g.html

I want show all Base Image Watermark for each product.

Sorry to some difficulty with foreign language.

Thank you for your support.

*Magento 1.9
*themeforest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put a watermark image on the thumbnail image to function.
Please view this [screenshot](https://goo.gl/agVGb4).
After that clear image cache.

Comment: Thank for screenshot ^^ @St3phan